# Pydot Error involving parsing ':' character followed by number

Tags: python, python-2.7, graphviz, anaconda, pydot

So I was using pydot in python 2.7 from Anaconda and noticed I keep getting errors when I attempt to use certain strings in Pydot.

The error I have isolated to:

```
import pydot


graph = pydot.Dot(graph_type='digraph', rankdir = 'LR')
S = 'Total Flow Count ' + ':' + str(3)
legend = pydot.Node('Legend', label=S, shape='rectangle')

graph.add_node(legend)
```

Whenever I run this I get the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path\of\my\code\errorisolate.py", line 13, in <module>
    graph.write_png('example5graph.png')
  File "c:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pydot.py", line 1609, in <lambda>
    lambda path, f=frmt, prog=self.prog : self.write(path, format=f, prog=prog))
  File "c:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pydot.py", line 1703, in write
dot_fd.write(self.create(prog, format))
  File "c:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pydot.py", line 1803, in create
status, stderr_output) )
InvocationException: Program terminated with status: 6. stderr follows: Error: c:\users\sidharth\appdata\local\temp\tmpxvwsls:3: syntax error near line 3

context: Legend [shape=rectangle, label=Total Flow Count >>>  : <<< 3];
```

### Analysis/Work So Far:

Somehow the combination of a colon character ':' followed by a number in str() format seems to raise an error. I tried to fix it by append the 'r' in front since I know that is a way to fix errors invlving the '\n' character. But even then no luck.

### Changes:

I removed the r as it appears to be causing a little confusion. I had kept r':' hoping to emulate the solution to the problem of non compiling newlines '\n', since pydot requires them to be listed as r'\n' where r is explicitly not defined.

As per:

[Pydot not playing well with line breaks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24442094/pydot-not-playing-well-with-line-breaks)

Comment: FWIW, `r'\n' ` is standard Python syntax. The `r` prefix means that it's a [raw string](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) literal, so `r'\n' ` contains two chars: a literal backslash followed by a literal `n`. Without the `r` prefix, `'\n' ` contains a single newline char.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this [issue number 38](https://github.com/erocarrera/pydot/issues/38) - Which says we cannot use special symbols (like colon) in node names or labels. The reason it has highlighted is -

> As with issue 28: The problem with the colon in Node names is that Graphviz 
>   will use them to specify a port where to attach edges, it's a Graphviz 
>   artifact. The way pydot supports them is to allow them in names, if you wish to 
>   simply have colon characters in the name simply add quotes to the string.
>
> For instance: (note the double quotes in the actual string):
>
> ```
> node = pydot.Node('"Testnode:###@"')
>
> print node.get_name()
> '"Testnode:###@"'
> ```

Though you may be better off not having colon in your name.

Comment: That's quite a hack, hmm... i'm hoping there will be some work around, besides the quotes but if not I guess it's a done deal

Comment: The [Issue 28](https://github.com/erocarrera/pydot/issues/28) is closed in status - *WontFix* , so I am guessing there is no other workaround or fix.