# nx.write_dot(...) generates redundant nodes when input nodes have a colon

Tags: python, graphviz, networkx, pygraphviz

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edge("A: test", 'B: test')

nx.write_dot(G,'so.dot')
```

Produces

[image: http://oi67.tinypic.com/2hrzrx3.jpg]

This is due to the colon.

`so.dot`:

```
strict digraph G {
A;
B;
"A: test" -> "B: test";
}
```

Notice it strips the colon and everything behind it.

If I manually change this to

```
strict digraph G {
"A: test";
"B: test";
"A: test" -> "B: test";
}
```

it's fine. In fact it doesn't matter if there are nodes, as long as there are edges.

If I remove the space between `:` and `t`, only A and B are generated.

I've tried escaping the colon in various ways, but that doesn't seem to work. I can manually delete the nodes every time, obviously, but a scripted solution would be preferable. (And not a second script that goes through the .dot file)

Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't a bug, it's a feature of the GraphViz Dot language syntax. The colon in a node name is used to specify input or output ports.

From the GraphViz docs, [Node, Edge and Graph Attributes](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#k:portPos)

> **portPos**
>
> Modifier indicating where on a node an edge should be aimed. It has the form `portname(:compass_point)?` or `compass_point`. If the
>   first form is used, the corresponding node must either have record
>   shape with one of its fields having the given *portname*, or have an
>   HTML-like label, one of whose components has a `PORT` attribute set to
>   *portname*.

However, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31524056/4014959) you *can* over-ride this behaviour by passing Graphviz a quoted node name, eg,

```
G.add_edge("'A: test'", "'B: test'")
```

Comment: Perfect. Out of curiosity, how did you find that answer? What search terms?

Comment: @svdc: It was a multi-stage process. :) FWIW, even though I'm not a Graphviz / DOT expert, I have been using it off & on for over 10 years (before I started using Python) so I've had a bit of practice searching for Graphviz info. But I must admit that I didn't know about ports before, or maybe I'd just forgotten about them. :) I've never used any of the Python Graphviz modules, my (admittedly simple) programs just create the DOT code directly.